# How to restrict how much of an image will be shown if the height is too big?

Tags: html, css

Imagine you have a 400 width 800 height image, however, you want the image to fill a 400 width x 400 height container BUT you don't want to scale it down, rather you want to slice off ( not display ) the bottom 400px of the image. How can I do that?

Comment: use `max-height` attribute of CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) seems to be what you look for. it can clip or scale down the image.

values that can be used :

```
object-fit: fill;
object-fit: contain;
object-fit: cover;
object-fit: none;
object-fit: scale-down;
```

you may also use [objec-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-position) to set how to clip it.*(if not specified, clipping is usually made from every side, showing the center)*
possible values.

```
object-position: center top;
object-position: 100px 50px;
```

---

examples using a 400x800 pixels image that should not exceed 50%'s height of viewport.

```css
img {
width:400px;
max-height:50vh;
object-fit: cover;
}
img + img {
object-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x800">
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x800">
```

see https://caniuse.com/#search=object-fit to checkout which browsers understands it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to get this done is to have the image inside a div of 400x400 and then hide the overflow content.

Useful links : [Overflow css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

```css
.image-holder {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-holder">

  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/236047/pexels-photo-236047.jpeg?cs=srgb&dl=landscape-nature-sky-236047.jpg&fm=jpg" alt="Image unavailable" />

</div>
```

Comment: Hmmm, for some reason after doing this, the container that contains the equivalent of your .image-holder becomes close to 10 000 pixels high, even though there's nothing after the first 1000-2000 pixels. I inspected the empty space and there's nothing there.